# Error with templates: no matching function call

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working my way through accelerated C++ & have hit a problem with Ex. 10.2
The questions involves rewriting a median function from a previous chapter, so that now median can be called with a vector or built-in array. The median function should also allow containers of any arithmetic type.

I cannot make the two calls to median detailed below - I receive the error message

```
No matching function for call to 'median'
```

I gather from some research that when Templates are used the Type should be known at compile time. Might this be the underlying issue? Is there a way to somehow pass the Type as a template argument?

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

template <class Iterator, class Type>
Type median(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    vector<Type> vec(begin,end);
    typedef typename vector<Type>::size_type container_sz;
    container_sz size = vec.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    container_sz mid = size/2;
    return size % 2 ==  0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> grades;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i){
        grades.push_back(i);
    }

    const int int_array[] = {2, 9, 4, 6, 15};
    size_t array_size = sizeof(int_array)/sizeof(*int_array);

    cout << median(int_array, int_array + array_size) << endl;   //error here: Semantic Issue, No matching function for call to 'median' 
    cout << median(grades.begin(), grades.end()) << endl;        //error here: Semantic Issue, No matching function for call to 'median' "

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using C++11 you can initialize the vector with `vector<int> grades = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` and `auto size = vec.size();` (i.e. removing the typedef). You can also replace `endl` with `"\n"` if you want to.

Comment: For first-pass readers benefit, kindly mark which line (including *both* if that is the case) that causes your compile-time error, with a comment (such as `// <== error here`). That said, the `Type` template parameter cannot be deduced from the calls you're making, which is ultimately the core issue. I think the standard-library-provided template [`iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) may be a clean solution to your problem.

Comment: And please include the full error message. It usually says what types it deduces in the function call, which you can compare with the actual expected types.

Comment: As a hint for the final solution: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits or if you are using C++11, a simple http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype

Comment: ok I made a edit to show where the errors occur. Iterator_traits looks like a nice solution but it hasn't been introduced so far in the book, which makes me think there is a another way to do it, and that I've missed something. Here is a link to the author's solution, which is similar to my own, and appears to attempt to deduce Type, in the same way I tried to.
https://github.com/bitsai/book-exercises/blob/master/Accelerated%20C%2B%2B/chapter10/10-2.hpp

Comment: The authors linked solution will only work if you specify a call with the underlying type, and as such it is not "deduced", it is outright-provided. I.e. You must call it as `median<int>(grades.begin(), grades.end());` This will work (obviously), but in the end you wouldn't do it this way once you had the arrow of `iterator_traits` in your quiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is rooted in the deduction of `Type` which is not possible with the arguments provided. You *can* do this using the standard library class `iterator_traits` as follows:

```
template <
    class Iterator, 
    class Type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
Type median(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    vector<Type> vec(begin,end);

    typedef typename vector<Type>::size_type container_sz;

    container_sz size = vec.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    container_sz mid = size/2;

    return size % 2 ==  0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}
```

The class `iterator_traits` dissects the Iterator type provided to determine what it is actually iterating (a little more complicated than that, but that is a decent summary). For more information on how it works, see the documentation of [`class iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). It is a most-handy mechanism for determining iterator value types.

Note: to ensure no unintended bypasses of the default template parameter `Type` declaration you can also do this:

```
template <class Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type median(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    if (begin == end)
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Type;
    std::vector<Type> vec(begin,end);
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    typename std::vector<Type>::size_type mid = vec.size()/2;
    return vec.size() % 2 ==  0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}
```

Its a little dense, and throws out most of the intermediate stuff, but if you stare at it long enough you'll understand how it works, and it reduces your template parameter list to only use the one thing you really care about; the `Iterator` type, which is trivially deduced by the parameters you provide to the function.

Comment: I posted a comment above with a link to the author's solution to the problem (https://github.com/bitsai/book-exercises/blob/master/Accelerated%20C%2B%2B/chapter10/10-2.hpp)
As I mentioned, your solution looks perfect but I havent come across it yet in the book, which suggests I'm missing somthing?

Comment: @Octave1 Likewise. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry first comment was posted too soon, now edited. Thanks for the answer. I think iterator_traits will come in useful. 
What I don't understand is that the author's solution seems to make the same error as mine, by deducing the type from the given iterator arguments. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't make *quite* the same error, the order allows the second template parameter type  to be deduced (Iterator) while requiring your still provide the first type. Using `iterator_traits` allows you to truly deduce the type from the iterator type rather than provided as a distinguished template parameter at call-time. This is important to understand, and I *think* you do. If you think this is some trivial problem, *don't*. It is more common than you think, and you actually did a pretty good job of analyzing where the problem may be and had reasonable suspicions as to the root cause.

Comment: ok I see your post above now, confusion over! I see that iterator_traits would be right way to go about this generally but I needed to know how it was done in this exercise, for the sake of my sanity :)
I've marked your response as correct, as it was the right answer, given the info you had at the time. I'll write out another answer re: median<int>(grades.begin(), grades.end()) so as to clarify that this is the correct way to answer Ex 10.2 in Accelerated C++.

Comment: @Octave1 if that is the case, you may wish to mark *your* answer as *the* answer for the question. Thats a tough call on your part, since the provided author solution is very specific to the level of exposure to the standard library, and once you've been exposed to iterator_traits, you would never do it any other way. Regardless, thanks for the props, and I'm glad it makes sense how it all fits together. Your comments in code in your answer are spot-on.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to tackle this issue, generally, is by using `iterator_traits` as described above. However in order to answer the particular question 10.2 from the book (which does not assume `Iterator_trait` knowledge), one can proceed as follows:
- Note class Type must be listed first, instead of class Iterator. Also, one must call `median<int>(grades.begin(), grades.end())` as opposed to `median(grades.begin(), grades.end())`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

template <class Type, class Iterator>       //the order allows the second template parameter type to be deduced (Iterator)                                           
Type median(Iterator begin, Iterator end)   //while requiring you still provide the first type
{

    vector<Type> vec(begin,end);

    //typedef typename vector<Type>::size_type container_sz;
    //container_sz size = vec.size()
    auto size = vec.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    //container_sz mid = size/2
    auto mid = size/2;

    Type ret = size % 2 ==  0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];

    return ret;
}


int main()
{

    vector<int> grades = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    const int int_array[] = {2, 9, 4, 6, 15};

    size_t array_size = sizeof(int_array)/sizeof(*int_array);

    cout << median<int>(int_array, int_array + array_size) << endl;  //must provide int here, in order to give the template the return type at compile time
    cout << median<int>(grades.begin(), grades.end()) << endl;


return 0;
```

}